# software updater GUI is empty

Tags: updates, update-manager

The software updater is able to successfully check for updates--when I open it, it provides me with a list of items to be updated (~600mb). Then when I click "install now", it just becomes this:
[image: blank software updater]

and it just lingers there with nothing happening. Any ideas on how to solve this?

I am running ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: It is not clear if this is a display issue. Is it any better if you use a different desktop theme?

Comment: Try reinstalling the `update-manager` package: `sudo apt install --reinstall update-manager`. If there are any errors, post the complete output in your question above.

Comment: I'm also curious to know what happens if you update and upgrade from the terminal.